# How to set website logo image on signup mail in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using rails 5 when user is registered in my website i am sending an email for him for account approval.I want to set website logo with email.
How we implement this in rails mailer view file 
[image]

### Html for mail template

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<title>nytApp Email</title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: 'arial', sans-serif !important;   font-size: 14px;   line-height: 20px;  color:#3e3e3e; background-color: #f5f5f5; font-weight: 300;">
        <!-- Container Table -->
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" style="margin:0 auto; background:#fff;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid #f5cd8f;">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 25px 15px 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #f5cd8f;">
                                            <table  align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><%= image_path('logo.png')%></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="color: #ff5e00; font-weight: 300; font-size: 20px;">Welcome to Nytapp</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 0 15px 20px;">
                                            <table  align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr><td height="10"></td></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Thank you for signing up as Events Promoter!</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td height="25"></td></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>You are ready to start posting your parties for free. Login to the portal by clicking on the link below:</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td height="10"></td></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><a href="https://night-app.herokuapp.com/admin" style="color: #00a8ff;">https://nytapp.com</a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td height="10"></td></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>If the above URL does not work try copying and pasting it into your browser.</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td height="8"></td></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>If you encounter any problem, please contact us at <a href="mailto:admin@nytapp.com" style="color: #333; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">admin@nytapp.com</a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td height="25"></td></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Thank you,</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>The Nytapp team</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td height="30"></td></tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="border-top: 1px solid #f5cd8f; vertical-align: middle;  padding: 10px 15px;">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <%= image_path('logo.png') %>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `<%= image_tag 'logo.png' %>` or `<%= image_tag(image_url('logo.png'))%>`

Answer (score 1):

In mailer you can't give relative path. So try upload your logo somewhere in cloud like s3 and give complete logo url in image tag source.

You can also use `asset_url` it compute complete url.

```
<%= image_tag asset_url('logo.png') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your html.erb file which is suppose to be send as mail
you need to wrtte something like this.....

```
<img src=" <%= Rails.application.secrets.host + "" +  asset_path("sd_logo.png") %>"
```